# Actualizar value del form al pulsar un boton o escribir en un input

Tags: javascript, php, html

Queria saber si hay alguna forma de con 3 divs al pulsar en alguno de ellos cambien el value, y aparte un input donde el valor que pongas se asigne a esa variable también.

```
    <form id="formulario_envio" method="POST" autocomplete="off" action="datos.php">

    
    <label for="tel">Teléfono</label>
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="123456789" value="123456789">

    <div class="price_button" id="price1" name="importe" value="" 
    onclick="price_change(this.id)">20€</div>

    <div class="price_button" id="price2" name="importe" value="" 
    onclick="price_change2(this.id)">50€</div>

    <div class="price_button" id="price3" name="importe" value="" 
    onclick="price_change3(this.id)">110€</div>

    <input>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

JS

```
    function price_change(id){
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("class", "price_button_active");
    document.getElementById("price2").setAttribute("class", "price_button");
    document.getElementById("price3").setAttribute("class", "price_button");
element.setAttribute("value", "20");}

    function price_change2(id){
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("class", "price_button_active");
    document.getElementById("price1").setAttribute("class", "price_button");
    document.getElementById("price3").setAttribute("class", "price_button");
    element.setAttribute("value", "30");}

    function price_change3(id)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("class",       "price_button_active");
        document.getElementById("price2").setAttribute("class", "price_button");
        document.getElementById("price1").setAttribute("class", "price_button");
element.setAttribute("value", "40");}
```

cuando envio esto al php no coge el value, no se que esta mal.

```
<?php
echo "datos.php";
print_r($_POST);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
echo $key .'='. $value.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Se envia bien el tel por ejemplo pero no coge el value que asigno con el setattribute.

Comment: Si lo quieres en html sin tener que generar ningun javascript puedes usar una combinación del atributo "onclick=" con el método [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) de javascript sobre el input con id precio. Eso te cambiaria el input y el resto que pides ya va solo al enviar el formulario.  Pruébalo y si tienes problemas con eso editas la pregunta y agregas el código que has intentado y el error que te ha dado para que la pregunta sea válida para ayudarte, pues ahora mismo no lo es al no haber hecho nada aun, tan solo lo has planteado.

Comment: perfecto, ya me hago una idea de como hacerlo, gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como han sugerido en los comentarios utiliza la funcion `onClick`

```html
<form>
<button value="20" onClick="changeValue(20)" name="precio">20€</button>
<button value="30" onClick="changeValue(30)" name="precio">30€</button>
<button value="40" onClick="changeValue(40)" name="precio">40€</button>
<input name="precio" id="precio" value="40€"/>
</form>

<script>
function changeValue(valor){
   document.getElementById("precio").value = valor + "€"
}
</script>


<?php
echo "datos.php";
print_r($_POST);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
echo $key .'='. $value.'<br>';
}?>
```

Comment: perdona acabo de editar la pregunta antes de ver tu contestacion, lo pruebo a ver.

Comment: funciona perfecto gracias! espero no haber liado la pregunta con la edición